# Why the source code of XXX-dev (or XXX-devel) is not distributed?

Tags: package-management

When I try to install the latest version of software on an old Linux server (I do not have root privilege for it), packages XXX-dev or XXX-devel are sometimes required, where XXX is the name of some library. For example, the pre-installation of libffi-devel is required for the installation of Python 3.7.4 in CentOS. Installing XXX-dev by `yum` or `apt` requires root privilege. Distributing the source codes of both XXX and XXX-dev sounds like a good way to enable normal users to install various software easily.

So, my question is why the source code of XXX-dev is not distributed? Is there a legitimate reason?

Comment: I misunderstood that the source code of XXX-dev is different from that of XXX. Thanks to the information given by Stephen Kitt and Daniel Farrell, now I was able to roughly understand what XXX-dev is. Actually, I can install Python 3.7.4 to a local location _without_ `libffi-dev` by making symbolic links of `/path_to_install_dir/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include/ffi*.h` in the directory `/path_to_install_dir/include` after installing libffi-3.2.1 from the source. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Erratum
I can install --> I was able to install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the source code of XXX-dev is not distributed?

Because you don't need to, or want to, compile every library you use when you compile, say, Python's ffi code.  You want to use *shared object files*, (Windows' equivalent is DLLs) to dynamically link to the libraries you want.  The source code is, in fact, available, as another answer suggests.  But this isn't what you need to build Python's ffi.  You need the *headers* and the *shared object file*.

> Installing XXX-dev by `yum` or `apt` requires root privilege.

This isn't because they don't install sources; it's because they operate at the system level.  You don't need to install source code, but you *do* need to have the following available:

- `XXX`, the *compiled* shared object files for the library
- `XXX-dev`, the source code *headers* that define functions in the library so they can be used within your code, but linked dynamically.

They don't have to be in a root-owned location, but they *do* need to be in a location that your compiler / linker / build toolchain will find.  This is true regardless of whether you build them from source.  But it's not trivial to set up all the little gubbins of the build process to be just right, which is why the distribution does it for you.

Unfortunately, this is a common scenario for Python, which draws heavily from the C side of the world, but leans on the operating system to provide those libraries as part of the standard build process.  It probably is possible to convince Python to use build components in user-owned locations.  I don't know how.  I'm going to recommend that you not make that your goal, but instead find a way to solve the problem of "you need to install libraries and don't have permissions":

- container technologies allow different userspace filesystems for processes, but your admin may not be comfortable giving you that access
- ask your admin to install each package you need
- use a different system for development on which you can install needed packages
- use a language with saner relationship to system libraries (Golang typically doesn't suffer this problem because its libraries *are* typically distributed as Golang sources, and the whole build process is more modern and works without root permissions)

Answer (score 2):

The source code of `-dev` and `-devel` packages *is* distributed; it’s included in the source code for the corresponding source package. For `libffi-devel` on CentOS, see [the `libffi` RPM git repository](https://git.centos.org/rpms/libffi/branches), and the corresponding source archive on [the upstream `libffi` distribution site](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/libffi/).